# WebAPI ModelState validation: [Range] enforces [Required]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I have the following requirements on a class member.
The `Name` can be either null or in the specified range. is there any way to achieve that with the WebApi annotations?

```
public class Product 
{
   [Range("abc", "abc2")]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: you should checkout https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.WebAPI

here you can add simply create validations via an fluent api

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Range` attribute in `DataAnnotations` try the `RegularExpression` attribute with this expression:

```
public class Product 
{
   [RegularExpression("abc|abc[0-2]")]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

This will match your sample alphabetic range.

It will also allow null or empty string values to pass validation because [the `RegularExpression` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks) **does not** apply the regular expression to null and empty string values.